# Laravel error with line code in double query builder relationship table

Tags: laravel

Helllo, i got unexpected '(', expecting '{' in

this is my code in blade :

```
 @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
 {{$invoice->userinvoiceperson->(function($userinvoiceperson) {return $userinvoiceperson->user->name;})}}
 @endforeach
```

This is my code in controller:

```
$invoices = Invoice::with(['userinvoiceperson' => function($query){
             $query->with('user')->get();
         }])->with('userinvoicesubaccount')->where('validate','=',0)->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])->get();
```

RelationShip Structure

invoices in relation with persons in person_id with userinvoiceperson function. persons in relation with user in user_id with user function.

Where did i miss ? Thank you..

EDIT : 
Instead, this line code works perfectly

```
{{$account->subaccount->sum( function($subaccount) { return $subaccount->subaccountinvoice->sum('amount');})}}
```

Comment: `->(` seems to cause the error. Are you missing the function name?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here but it doesn't look like proper code for a view.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, i eddited post for you to see a similar line code working for me

Comment: @Devon I use it and it works, i got the sum i want..

Comment: Well, it may work, but it's not very readable.  Do you have multiple subaccounts?  If so, why is it named subaccount?  Same goes for userinvoiceperson.

Comment: @Devon yes before this line a use a foreach($accounts as $account)   cuz i have multiple accounts. and for each account  i have multiple subaccounts.

Comment: Maybe it's a language barrier, but that's my point here.  Your relationship should be named "subaccounts" not "subaccount" because you have multiple.  It's not very readable to have collections with a singular name.

Comment: you didn't add any method like in your second example you have `sum`

Comment: @C2486 yes, because this time i dont need a sum, i just need a value of a simple cell ..

Comment: @Devon ok, thank you sir, i try to find where i missed.

Comment: @yassinej so do you have multiple "userinvoiceperson" or just one?  That's why I emphasized my previous point.  If you have multiple, which one's value do you want?  If you have only one, then you don't need a "map/reduce" like function to get the value.

Comment: can you share sample output for `$invoice->userinvoiceperson` and what you are looking ?

Comment: Thank u again for ur interest. i eddited post with full information. 
my dd($invoices) works. I have the correct relationship with invoices / persons/ users

Comment: That doesn't answer either of our questions.  You also aren't loading the distant relationship correctly.  You should never use get() within a query builder closure.  Unfortunately, I can't spend any more time on your issue.  I think you need to spend more time reading the laravel docs and learning about the data types you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write

```
{{$invoice->userinvoiceperson->user->name}}
```

Thank you